# Using RSA key pair for file encryption

Tags: public-key, file-encryption, openssl

I'm looking for a way to perform encrypted nightly backups of a server I administer, without storing the decryption key on the server.

A form of PK encryption seems ideal for this, as I can store the public key on the server, and the private key somewhere else private (like on a post-it attached to my monitor, or for real security, under my matress).  If I need to restore from backups, I can get the private key out of hiding.  At least, so goes the theory...

However, only a small amount of data can be encrypted with an RSA public key, so this needs to be a symmetric key used for the actual encryption, which must be generated at the time of file encryption and stored alongside the backup so I don't have to store this on the server.

Given the above, do the following two simple shell scripts make security sense, and what (if any) existing and proven Open-Source software is available to do something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
#this is the encryption system used like this: ./crypt.sh publickey.pem mycleartextfile.txt

PUBKEY=$1
CLEARTEXT_FILE=$2

SESSION_KEY=`openssl rand 256`
echo "$SESSION_KEY" | openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -pubin -inkey "$PUBKEY" -out "$CLEARTEXT_FILE".key
echo "$SESSION_KEY" | openssl enc -in "$CLEARTEXT_FILE" -e -blowfish -out "$CLEARTEXT_FILE".openssl -pass stdin
```

...and the decryption script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#usage ./decrypt privatekey.pem encrypted-file-session.key encrypted-file
PRIVATE_KEY=$1
SESSION_KEY_CRYPT=$2
CIPHERTEXT_FILE=$3

openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -inkey "$PRIVATE_KEY" -in "$SESSION_KEY_CRYPT" \
| openssl enc -d -blowfish -in "$CIPHERTEXT_FILE" -out "$CIPHERTEXT_FILE".out -pass stdin
```

Any thoughts on this are much appreciated.

Comment: You've got the right idea. Note: openssl rand 256 genertes 256 bytes of output. 256 bits would be enough for a symmetric key.

Comment: openssl rand 256's output is binary. How sure are you that your SESSION_KEY variable can hold 256 bytes that may include binary zero bytes? A test script I just tried couldn't, under a Linux bash shell.

Comment: @BrockHansen I hadn't considered that, but I tried a bunch of times in GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release on Debian Sid and it seems to work fine. I will however look into this concern. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Why blowfish? Doesn't it have a 64-bit block size? Why not AES?

Comment: Are unauthorized or otherwise unexpected changes to the backup file part of your threat model? I've never used the openssl command myself. Does the ciphertext output include any message authentication code when you don't explicitly specify a mode?

Comment: @BrockHansen  I haven't got that far yet, but considered it.  I believe changing `-blowfish` to an authenticated mode such as `-aes-128-gcm` may provide this protection, but as it stands, I don't really know the answer, and doing that causes openssl to outputs "bad decrypt" even though the output data is identical to the input.

Comment: Regarding null bytes: zsh supports null bytes in variables. I suggest you use that, or switch to a proper scripting language. To see that it breaks in bash, try `bash -c 'LOL=$(echo -en "d\x00d"); echo -n "$LOL" | hd'`

Comment: Have a look at AES in XTS mode, and have a look at the relevant questions about xts on here

Comment: Why not just use GnuGPG ? Don't roll your own encryption protocol.

Comment: Note that currently you are using the symmetric session key as password. That also explains why the 256 byte "key" works: it is first converted using the BytesToKey function. It also explains why you don't need an IV - a salt is automatically inserted in front of the ciphertext (after a 8 byte magic).

Comment: @JanusTroelsen zsh may handle null in a variable, but *openssl* doesn't handle null in a *password* either as an argument with `-k` or `-pass pass:str` or read from `-kfile` or `-pass file:name|fd:num|stdin` as here) and for the latter it effectively does `gets` and thus doesn't handle newline either. +Idrumm `enc` doesn't handle AEAD ciphers (GCM or CCM) -- although it might in the future; RT#4228 just opened 2 weeks ago proposes to add it